# Getting path of right click in unity 3D editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create an extension for the Unity 3D Editor and have an custom asset type. During the process of creation this I recognized that I would improve the UX/usability if I can specify the path where I want to create the asset by using right click. But I fail to get the context path of the right click and I cannot find any hints on google or at the unity scripting api. Below you can see an image of the process I tried to describe above.

[image: Asset creation process]

Here is the code that is responsible for handling the context creation "event".

```
[MenuItem("Assets/Create/Chat")]
public static void createChatViaMenu() {
    Chat c = Chatter.createDefaultChat();

    // This is the part where I want to insert the relative path.
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(c, "Assets/" + c.Title + ".asset");
}
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution can be found in [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/106698/70015) answer by Hash Buoy.

The core information I needed was that I could get the relative path via `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (Selection.activeObject)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    [UnityEditor.MenuItem("Assets/Create/Get Current Path")]
    static void GetCurrentPath(UnityEditor.MenuCommand menuCommand)
    {
        foreach(var g in UnityEditor.Selection.assetGUIDs)
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(g));
    }
```

In this case, GUIDs will consist of one element.
Debug.Log displays the current path from where the dropdown menu was called.

Example: Assets/Scenes or the like

It is also necessary to check if assets is selected.

Example: Assets/Scenes/Main.scene

Answer (score 2):

#### Use built-in property

If your asset is simple and doesn't need special treatment, you should use **built-in property** to generate a "create asset" menu.

```
[CreateAssetMenu( menuName = "Wappen Asset/WaveBankData" )]
public class WaveBankData : ScriptableObject
{
```

And it will magically added to right click menu -> Create. Has same functionality as Unity's one. It will be created in current browser location, prompt for a rename, etc.

[image]

---

#### Via MenuItem callback

If you really want to use customized **MenuItem**. Here is how TextMesh pro determine current right-click folder. If you call `Selection.assetGUIDs` under MenuItem callback, it will guarantee current displaying folder (the one that you clicked on its empty space)

For full script, see your own `\Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Editor\TMP_ColorGradientAssetMenu.cs`

```
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/TextMeshPro/Color Gradient", false, 115)]
    public static void CreateColorGradient(MenuCommand context)
    {
        string filePath;

        if (Selection.assetGUIDs.Length == 0)
            filePath = "Assets/New TMP Color Gradient.asset";
        else
            filePath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(Selection.assetGUIDs[0]);
```

---

#### (BONUS) The TRUE Project browser current directory

Is hidden inside internal unity `ProjectWindowUtil.TryGetActiveFolderPath` static function and needs reflector to access it. If you are coder wiz and really want to have it, here it is. (For non coder, I wont explain this, please do C# research on your own)

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Reflection;

    // Define this function somewhere in your editor class to make a shortcut to said hidden function
    private static bool TryGetActiveFolderPath( out string path )
    {
        var _tryGetActiveFolderPath = typeof(ProjectWindowUtil).GetMethod( "TryGetActiveFolderPath", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic );

        object[] args = new object[] { null };
        bool found = (bool)_tryGetActiveFolderPath.Invoke( null, args );
        path = (string)args[0];

        return found;
    }
```

Note: tested in Unity 2019.4.19f.

[Also cross-posted with gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106697/getting-path-of-right-click-in-unity-3d-editor/189456#189456)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, using `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath` with `Selection` never returns a folder, instead of that always returns the last asset file you have clicked on (the one being shown in the inspector).

Here is my try, expanding the proposal given by @Владимир of using `assetGUIDs`, in case you needed full path (but it would be easy to modify it to return a relative path):

```cs
    private static string GetClickedDirFullPath()
    {
        string clickedAssetGuid = Selection.assetGUIDs[0];
        string clickedPath      = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(clickedAssetGuid);
        string clickedPathFull  = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), clickedPath);

        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(clickedPathFull);
        return attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) ? clickedPathFull : Path.GetDirectoryName(clickedPathFull);
    }
```